# Pass multiple values through header function

Tags: php

I want to set a message for the user to see in php, but I'm having issues crossing controllers. Here was my first try:

```
     if($revOutcome > 0){
         $message = "<p>Review updated!</p>";
         header('Location: /acme/accounts/index.php?action=seshLink');
         exit;
     }
```

And here was my second try:

```
     if($revOutcome > 0){
         header('Location: /acme/accounts/index.php?action=seshLink&message=Update was successful!');
         exit;
     }
```

I have an `isset` in the view that checks if `$message` is set, and if it is, echo what is displayed in `$message`. But for some reason, it's not displaying. Here is the code for the view:

```
<?php
if (isset($message)) {
echo $message;
}
?>
```

And here is the switch case statement `seshLink`:
  case 'seshLink':
      $userId = $clientData['clientId']; 
      $revData = getCliRev($userId);

```
    if(!$revData){
        $message = "<p>No reviews here yet. Write your first one today!</p>";
            include '../view/admin.php';
            exit;
    }
        else {
            $RevDisplay = buildAdminReviewDisplay($revData);
        }

  include '../view/admin.php';
  break;
```

I really don't know why `$message` isn't displaying.

Comment: Because you are making a request call (parameters through url) which means that you need to get your variables using `$_GET` array like `if (isset($_GET["message"]))`

Comment: @JorgeCampos That worked!! Thank you! I'd be happy to accept your answer too :)!!

Comment: Glad that it worked. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are making a request call (parameters through url) which means that you need to get your variables using `$_GET` array like

```
...
if (isset($_GET["message"]))
   ...
```

Comment: `echo $_GET["message"];`